# Angular5 PathLocationStrategy hot reload with webpack-dev-server

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-ui-router

I am required to use Angular router's PathLocationStrategy for routes but after switching from Hash I am no longer able to use the hot-reload functionality of the built-in ng serve webpack-dev-server on some routes.

On some routes on hot-reload or page refresh I will receive errors like:

polyfills.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

While some routes will load fine.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: What is the URL for that file on the pages that work and the pages that don't work?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel 
localhost:4300/ works
localhost:4300/dashboard (in main module) works 
localhost:4300/places/444 (lazy loaded module) does not work

Comment: What is the URL being loaded for the js file that is failing (fire the ones that work and the one that doesn't)? Not the page URL but rather the URL actually being requested for the resource in question

Comment: Do you have a base href set up in your html?